# calling checkchanged event only upon checking not unchecking

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have CheckChanged event behind Checkbox, it is called whether i tick or un-tick checkbox but i only wat to call this event when check box is checked not on uncheck.

code:

```
protected void chkIsHead_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtSelectedID.Text != "")
        {
            int DepID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["depID"]);
            ManageDesignationsBizz mngDesig = new ManageDesignationsBizz();
            bool isHead = mngDesig.SelectIsHeadExistsByDepID(DepID);

            if (isHead == true)
            {
                HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "HeadExists";
                HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
                chkIsHead.Checked = false;
                HiddenFieldShowHideButtons.Value = "True";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            int DepID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["depID"]);
            ManageDesignationsBizz mngDesig = new ManageDesignationsBizz();
            bool isHead = mngDesig.SelectIsHeadExistsByDepID(DepID);

            if (isHead == true)
            {
                HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "HeadExists";
                HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
                chkIsHead.Checked = false;
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` condition to check the state of the `Checked` property of the `CheckBox` control. As the following:

```
protected void chkIsHead_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkIsHead.Checked)
    {
        // put your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This alternate might work*

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Check" 
    AutoPostBack="True" OnClick="return chkSelected();" 
    OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chkSelected() {
        var chk = document.getElementById('<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>');
        if (chk.checked) {
            __doPostBack('<%= CheckBox1.ClientID %>', '');
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```